# Get High Quality Audio from HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi

I'm using the RPi as an audio streamer. However the audio from the 3.5mm jack isn't great. Is there a way I can use the HDMI socket to output audio to my stereo? My stereo has RCA audio input (separate white and red plugs)

[image]

(3.5mm may also be okay with an adaptor.)

Will a HDMI to RCA cable do this for me?

Comment: What kind of stereo is that with 2 LAN ports?

Comment: Never mind I used Google's search by image and .. wow it came up with [Sonos Wireless Audio System](http://www.sonos.com/shop/products/connect) Cooooool!

Answer (score 3):

I actually use a HDMI to VGA (with build in active chip) to use on older monitors.

But I see now for roughly the same price of £10 they also have an audio out jack.(Remember to look for cables WITH the chip or external power. Not the cheap £1 cables. THey won't work)

[image]

Then you can just use 3.5mm jack to Stereo RCA's  to go into your audio system.

There are various devices out there. THis one gives you more outputs like the higher quality digital audio out and rgb video combinations for about £25 :)

[image]

Just search [ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=hdmi%20convertor&_sacat=0&_odkw=hdmi%20to%20rca&_osacat=0&_from=R40) or [amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=hdmi%20convertor) for HDMI convertors (with active chip or external power)

Comment: What's the audio quality like from the HDMI port for playing music?

Comment: HDMI is digital, so whatever the source quality is at. If its Mono, it will be Mono, if its DTS 5.1 then you need to use SPDIF output to a source that will handle it otherwise its just Stereo.

Answer (score 1):

HDMI transfers digital audio, while your stereo RCA audio inputs require analog audio. A simple cable will not do it.

There are many HDMI splitters which allow you to separate the digital audio from the HDMI output, which you can then plug in to any device that can convert digital audio to analog audio. These can be found as S/PDIF to RCA converters as well as more professional DAC boxes.

However, this is probably going to be costly, and a mess with the wires. If at all possible, I would suggest either buying a new stereo which takes in digital audio directly (or even HDMI), or buying a USB connected sound card with good quality sound output.